# Storing dictionaries in mongo

Tags: mongodb

Is there any reliable and fast database architecture that allows to store a dictionary(containing up to hundred thousand words) using mongodb?

Answer (score 2):

For optimal performance, MongoDB schema design must be custom-tailored for each application's unique access patterns. It's better to study general MongoDB design techniques than specific architectures (which may not match your specific application).

Having said that, [Wordnik](http://www.10gen.com/customers/wordnik) is a great case-study:

- Similar application: real-time dictionary
- 20 billion records stored in 3.5 terabytes of MongoDB
- Many online presentations sharing their MongoDB knowledge/experiences

  - [Inside Wordnik's Architecture](http://www.slideshare.net/fehguy/inside-wordniks-architecture) gives a more "macro" view of Wordnik's 
    architecture.
  - [Lots of other slides](http://www.slideshare.net/fehguy)

Here is how Wordnik apparently modeled their words:
[image]
source: [MongoDB Schema Design](http://www.slideshare.net/kbanker/mongodb-schema-design)